Need to use a changing variable inside another variable Power Automate
So in this expression in Power Automate I want to switch x by numbers from 0 to 85
%JSONfields['walk']['valueArray'][%x%]['valueObject']['obj']['content']%
The problem is that I can't use %% inside other %%.
How would I try to solve this?
I tried using a Python script to write the line of code to be:
%JSONfields['walk']['valueArray'][0]['valueObject']['obj']['content']%
%JSONfields['walk']['valueArray'][1]['valueObject']['obj']['content']%,    

depending of the iteration it is at, but Power Automate wont accept it

Since x variable is inside the evaluation block it does not need % sign around it:
%JSONfields['walk']['valueArray'][x]['valueObject']['obj']['content']%


If you find my answer useful - please vote for it or mark as "Accepted".

Just remove the inside %% and it works.
